# How to use awk to reformat two different types of csv files into one common format?

Tags: unix, awk

I have a bunch of CSV files in one of the two following formats.

File `type-a.csv`:

```
name,age,breed,vip
jack,10,golden,no
mary,3,poodle,yes
```

File `type-b.csv`:

```
name,age,membership start,membership end,breed,vip
hazel,2,2018,2019,pit bull,yes
pot roast,4,2020,2021,lab,yes
```

I have two questions. First, I'm trying to reformat these files into one common format using awk. Like this:

```
age,name,type,breed
10,jack,A,golden
3,mary,A,poodle
2,hazel,B,pit bull
4,pot roast,B,lab
```

This is the code I have right now. I used `find` to find all the CSV files satisfying the naming convention. However, I'm not sure how to proceed with `awk`.

```
#find all csv files
for f in $(find $dir -iname 'type-*.csv' -type f)
do
        awk '
                BEGIN { Name=""; Type=""; Age=0; Breed=""; }                         
done
```

The second question is, these files are all named like `type-*.csv`. For example, `type-a.csv`, `type-b.csv`, etc. And I want to include these types into the output CSV file as the third `type` column, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You have several input files, and you want a single output file, is that right?

Comment: yes, I want one single output file. @glennjackman

Comment: Once you've gotten an answer, your scope for editing the question is limited.  You've significantly changed the question, invalidating the answer, which is not allowed.  If absolutely necessary, you can amend the question by _adding_ extra information, but you should not delete salient parts of the question so it is no longer clear why the answer(s) is (are) written the way they are.  I've rolled back the question to the original version so that the answer remains relevant.  You did propose an edit to the answer — that's not really a good idea. Leave the question alone once you have an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do

```sh
{
    echo "age,name,type,breed"
    find . -name 'type-?.csv' -exec awk '
        BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","}
        FNR == 1 {
            type = toupper(substr(FILENAME, length(FILENAME)-4, 1))
            next
        }
        {print $2, $1, type, $(NF - 1)}
    ' '{}' +
} > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the type of the file is related to the number of fields, why not simply do:

```sh
echo "age,name,type,breed" > output.csv
for f in $(find "$dir" -iname 'type-*.csv' -type f); do
  awk 'BEGIN{FS = OFS = ","}
    (FNR > 1){if (NF == 4) print $1, $2, "A", $3; else print $1, $2, "B", $5}' "$f"
done >> output.csv
```

Comment: Do just two files qualify as "a bunch of files"?  My impression is that there's more than two files, but there are only two file formats.